# ERROR: manifest for docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:vv2.2.3 not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry

Tags: docker-compose, whatsapi

I am trying to integrate whatsup API gettin following error.

Pulling wacore (docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:vv2.2.3)...

ERROR: manifest for docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:vv2.2.3 not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go and update the version of WA_API from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/changelog/

seems like the images expires

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove V when you setup

```
export WA_API_VERSION=2.27.12
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the above answer, there's no version vv2.2.3. Please see the changelog and use the correct version. Example: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v2.23.4